# Activity destroyed using Fragment

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have a ListView in `ListView.class`, when the User clicks on one item (let's say item at position =0) Fragment6 should be opened.

Additionally, I have a `HandleListClick.class` that gets the position ( e.g. position = 0) and then uses a `switch` to open a fragment, but I get an error.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Activity has been destroyed

How can I handle this annoying problem? My activity is declared in Manifest.

Here is my `ListView.class`

```
  listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {

            // ListView Clicked item index
            int itemPosition     = position;

            // ListView Clicked item value
            String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);


                if (position==0){
                    HandleListClick handleListClick = new HandleListClick();
                    handleListClick.getItemPosition(0);
                }
}
```

Here is my `handleListClick.class`

```
public class HandleListClick extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_handle_list_click);
}


public void getItemPosition(int position) {
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            Fragment6 frag6 = null;
            frag6 = new Fragment6();
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.framelayout, frag6)
                    .commit();


    }
}
```

}

Here is my `Fragment6.java`

```
public class Fragment6 extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragmentdescrip6, container,false);
    return v;



 //  ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(
  //         R.layout.fragmentdescrip6, container, false);

 //  return rootView;
}
```

}

Here is `activity_handle_list_click.xml`

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
      xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.user.app.HandleListClick">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id= "@+id/framelayout"
        >


    </FrameLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

And here is `fragmentdescrip6.xml`

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/frag6"

    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfrag6label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="foo"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#FFFF4444"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="17dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textfrag6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textfrag6label"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:text="some Text" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it this way

```
 listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
            int position, long id) {

                // ListView Clicked item index
                int itemPosition     = position;

                // ListView Clicked item value
                String  itemValue    = (String) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);


                if (position==0){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, HandleListClick.class);
                    intent.putExtra("POSITION", position);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                   /* HandleListClick handleListClick = new HandleListClick();
                    handleListClick.getItemPosition(0);*/
                }
            }
```

**Change the Activity code**

```
    public class HandleListClick extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_handle_list_click);
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            int pos = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION",0);
            getItemPosition(pos);
        }


        public void getItemPosition(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    Fragment6 frag6 = null;
                    frag6 = new Fragment6();
                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.framelayout, frag6)
                            .commit();


            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: But what happens if I have position = 1 in addition? Then `int pos = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION",0);` does not work, right?

Comment: if position ==1, then onCreate of HandleListClick class will not be called because of we have put a condition for position==0 only, in onItemClick().

Comment: But what can I do to handle more positions? I do have 5 in total.

Comment: then remove the position==0 condition from onItemClick,  after removing it you can get position of every item clicked at getItemPosition(int position) method automatically, and by applying switch case for more fragment you can do your task.

Comment: I see, but what do I have to put in `int pos = intent.getIntExtra("POSITION",0);` with what do I have to replace the 0 ?

Comment: you have to do nothing here, 0 is default position.

Comment: Thank you very very much. All worked. Have a nice day.

Comment: i m glad it works :) i am Indian and here its 12:30 AM Night, so Good Night :)

Comment: Oh, sorry :d Then have good night, mate :) Greetings from Berlin.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148134/discussion-between-blnpwr-and-aniruddh-parihar).